# Computing difference between rows in a data frame

Tags: r

I have a data frame. I would like to compute how "far" each row is from a given row. Let us consider it for the 1st row. Let the data frame be as follows:

```
> sampleDF  

   X1  X2  X3  
   1   5   5  
   4   2   2  
   2   9   1  
   7   7   3
```

What I wish to do is the following:

1. Compute the difference between the 1st row & others: `sampleDF[1,]-sampleDF[2,]`
2. Consider only the absolute value: `abs(sampleDF[1,]-sampleDF[2,])`
3. Compute the sum of the newly formed data frame of differences: `rowSums(newDF)`

Now to do this for the whole data frame.

`newDF <- sapply(2:4,function(x) { return (abs(sampleDF[1,]-sampleDF[x,]));})`

This creates a problem in that the result is a transposed list. Hence,

`newDF <- as.data.frame(t(sapply(2:4,function(x) { return (abs(sampleDF[1,]-sampleDF[x,]));})))`

But another problem arises while computing rowSums:

```
> class(newDF)
[1] "data.frame"
> rowSums(newDF)
Error in base::rowSums(x, na.rm = na.rm, dims = dims, ...) : 
  'x' must be numeric
> newDF
  X1 X2 X3
1  3  3  3
2  1  4  4
3  6  2  2
>
```

**Puzzle 1**: Why do I get this error? I did notice that newDF[1,1] is a list & not a number. Is it because of that? How can I ensure that the result of the sapply & transpose is a simple data frame of numbers?

So I proceed to create a global data frame & modify it within the function:

`sapply(2:4,function(x) { newDF <<- as.data.frame(rbind(newDF,abs(sampleDF[1,]-sampleDF[x,])));})`

```
> newDF
  X1 X2 X3
2  3  3  3
3  1  4  4
4  6  2  2
> rowSums(outDF)
 2  3  4 
 9  9 10 
>
```

This is as expected.

**Puzzle 2**: Is there a cleaner way to achieve this? How can I do this for every row in the data frame (shown above is only for "distance" from row 1. Would need to do this for other rows as well)? Is running a loop the only option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To put it in words, you are trying to compute the Manhattan distance:

```
dist(sampleDF, method = "Manhattan")
#    1  2  3
# 2  9      
# 3  9 10   
# 4 10  9  9
```

Regarding your implementation, I think the problem is that your inner function is returning a `data.frame` when it should return a numeric vector. Doing `return(unlist(abs(sampleDF[1,]-sampleDF[x,])))` should fix it.

Comment: Thank you so much for the clarification. While I knew I had to compute a distance, it didn't strike me to check out if R had something to compute distances. The unlist within the function helped solve my problem as well. Now to see if I can employ custom methods to compute distances.